# Display HTMl link page in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I am trying to make website in Asp.Net MVC 2.I have a text on my page and I am trying to create link to it . My code is as follows

```
     <a href="<%= MyPage.aspx %>">Link</a>
```

However I am getting Resource error.

What am I missing ?? Is this the right way to call a page in MVC ??

Thank you All

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of ways of doing it.

Firstly, you can use [Html.ActionLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink%28v=vs.108%29.aspx):

```
@Html.ActionLink("Link", "action name")
```

Secondly, you can use [Url.Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action%28v=vs.108%29.aspx):

```
<a href="@Url.Action("action name")">Link</a>
```

As you can see, the difference is that `Html.ActionLink` will generate the complete HTML for an `a` tag, whereas `Url.Action` will only generate the URL to the specified action.

Both of them have several overloads which allow you to pass any extra data you might require, so I'd encourage you to check the links above to see what they're capable of.